# Apache + Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dns

i need this kind of configuration:

Apache will respond to my blog if it is called on www.mydomain.com and i want to tomcat to respond to thirddomain.mydomain.com

I've configured a worker to respond to thirddomain.mydomain.com in this way:

```
<VirtualHost thirddomain.mydomain.com:80>
        JkMount /*    myworker
        ServerName thirddomain.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

my worker is configured in this way:

```
worker.list=myworker
worker.myworker.port=8009
worker.myworker.host=thirddomain.mydomain.com
worker.myworker.type=ajp13
```

i've also a standard virtualhost that point to www

```
<VirtualHost www.mydomain.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

the server.xml on tomcat is this one:

```
   <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="thirddomain.mydomain.com">
      <Host name="thirddomain.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" resolveHost="false"
                   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
```

The problem is that apache is responding on both www and mythirddomain. How i can configure it to respond on different third domains?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First map "thirddomain.mydomain.com" (subdomain) to a valid directory, to check if that config works without ajp and Tomcat (comment out JKMount).

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/anotherDir/index.html
```

If that works uncomment JKMount and change this to use an ip:

```
worker.myworker.host=thirddomain.mydomain.com
```

should be:

```
worker.myworker.host=127.0.0.1
```

(I guess Tomcat is on the same server as your web server). Add the worker name in the Engine element as well:

```
 <Engine jvmRoute="myworker" name="Catalina" defaultHost="thirddomain.mydomain.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mod_proxy for this type of configuration. You can follow this link to learn more about mod_proxy module of apache. [Apache Mod_Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Add the below two lines in your `httpd.conf`.

```
ProxyPass thirddomain.mydomain.com/ localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse thirddomain.mydomain.com/ localhost:8080
```

Here your Apache HTTP Server will act as an reverse proxy.